# why asp.net uses GUID column instead of bigint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

why asp.net uses GUID column instead of bigint for the Membership, Role, Profile providers?

i'm not sure if any of those tables will ever needs to be replicated or merged with another table which as i heard are the most acceptable reasons for using guids over int/bigint.

Comment: The ASP.NET membership subsystem was probably designed by the Sharepoint folks..... :-)

Comment: @marc_s -- honestly, I think there is some weight to the theory that the bulk of ASP.NET 2.0's features (including membership) was specc'd for SharePoop.

Comment: Never merged with another table, ever, throughout all the systems using ASP.NET in the world? That seems unlikely.

Comment: ASP.NET membership is set up to support multiple applications from a single database.  It is, on the contrary, VERY possible that a situation might arise where databases are merged along with their accompanying membership tables, or that membership would be centralized into a single database within a group of applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It possibly uses GUID kind of for the opposite side of why you wonder if it should: Because they creators of that database, intended to be used by many different sites, couldn't guarantee that it *wouldn't* be used in situations where it would need to be merged with other data.

Answer (score 2):

The main benefit of guids is that they are perfectly unique across all your data and tables; way, way more head-room in terms of values

Answer (score 2):

Using Guids also helps one mate the membership up with Active Directory and windows SIDs. Definitely could not do that with a system generated integer.

Comment: can you please explain why you can't do that with integer?

Comment: Because windows SIDs are GUIDs.

Comment: well, i guess because they also wanted to use Membership, Role, Profile providers with active directory they didn't have a choise.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind also that the membership, roles, and profile providers support the roles and memberships for multiple applications in one set of tables. If you had to maintain auto incrementing columns for all these applications it would be a maintenance nightmare with all the deletes that can take place throughout an enterprise solution. The GUIDs aka unique identifier in MS SQL Server makes this much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the other way, why wouldn't you use a GUID?
Size and inefficiency of index would be the main ones. Both of those are only real concerns with huge volumes of data, which your examples aren't.

If it had been bigint and you had three built in profiles everybody's first one would have been four, now to merge two instances you have to rekey one of them. If you haven't been responsible and used surrogate keys everywhere, nightmare.

So when I'm looking at this in my designs, my question is, can I afford **not** to use GUID....

Comment: Just [read **how** bad GUID as clustering keys are](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) and you might change your mind.....